# Ext JS Cannot read property 'getItems' of null

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an Ext 4.2.1 application with an Ext.form.Panel, and when trying to send the form field values to the server, I need to first determine one of the values to do a switch on.  Sorry I can't provide a complete example, but the trouble I have is with this command:

```
form.getForm().findField('TASK_ID')
```

In my application if throws:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItems' of null
    at Ext.define.getFields (ext-all-debug.js:89221)
    at Ext.define.findField (ext-all-debug.js:89471)
    at Ext.Ajax.request.success
```

Line 89221 is as follows:

```
getFields: function() {
    return this.monitor.getItems();
},
```

I'm not sure what `monitor` is, so I'm a little out of my depth debugging this.  Does anyone have any insight as to what might be wrong or what I can check?

Comment: Is the form rendered?

Comment: `this.monitor` is set to null when `destroy` is called on `Ext.form.Basic` object. When in the lifetime of the form do you call the `findField` method?

Comment: thanks for your comments; this has helped me find the issue (race condition)

Answer (score 3):

When creating form in `Ext.window.Window` after `window.close()` I got the same error. Debugging my source code, I found out `window` handles `autoRender` again, it actually conflicts at my singleton `window` effect, as follow code:

```
getUpdateGroupWindow: function(){
        var me = this;
        if(me.updateGroupWindow == null){
            me.updateGroupWindow = Ext.create('MyApp.view.groupEditWindow');
        }
        return me.updateGroupWindow;
    },
```

read api: http://extjs-doc-cn.github.io/ext4api/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-closeAction window `closeAction` defaults to "destroy", remove the window from the DOM and destroy it and all descendant components. The window will not be available to be re-displayed via the show method, another value 'hide': hide the window by setting visibility to hidden and applying negative offsets. The window will be available to be re-displayed via the `show` method.

My final code for example:

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.view.groupEditWindow',{
    extend:'Ext.window.Window',
    title:'修改信息',
    width: 400,
    closeAction: 'hide', //fix error config
    modal: true,
    groupForm:null,
    getGroupForm:function(){
        var me = this;
        if(me.groupForm == null){
            me.groupForm = Ext.create('MyApp.view.EditGroupForm');
        }
        return me.groupForm;
    },
    
    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [me.getGroupForm()],
            buttons: [{
                text: '取消',
                handler: function() {
                    me.close();
                }
            }]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```